# Custom ILogger is not using overridden default LogLevel from code

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, configuration, ilogger

I have implemented a `custom Ilogger` following steps from microsoft document [Implement a custom logging provider in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/tree/main/docs/core/extensions/snippets/configuration/console-custom-logging)

My problem is I want to override the `Default` LogLevel in `appsetting.json` using `IOption<T>` from code.

I have made following changes in microsoft sample code highlighted in yellow

[image]

[image]

with above changes I am getting below output

[image]

I was expecting the output to include Information message also after I override the `default`  `loglevel` from code. So my expected output is

[image]

which I am getting only after setting  "Default": "Information" in appsetting.json only

Comment: Please, do not post your code as screenshots.

Comment: Actully the code is all explained in the link from microsoft website so I only want to highlight the changes I made in original code. so I used screenshots for others to replicate the issue